# the selectcommand property has not been initialized before calling fill c# in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written following code in wpf but when clicked on button it shows an error.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=RAMANDEEP-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=RamandeepSingh; integrated security=true");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ContactManager", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();                
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "ContactManager");
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            listBox1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception we)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(we.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: would you care to share the error with us ?

Comment: the SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty straight forward .you are trying to fill the adapter first and then calling the select command. Which is obviously wrong. Change it to

```
 da.SelectCommand = cmd;
 da.Fill(ds, "ContactManager");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sequence matters, try this. :)

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""data source=RAMANDEEP-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=RamandeepSingh; integrated security=true"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from ContactManager";
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
}

listBox1.ItemSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: hi, i used your code but it shows same error "the SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.

Comment: I don't see any reason for failing, can you try this one?

Comment: hi, i again used your code now, when i clicked on button it doesn't perform any functionality,

Comment: means it is not returning any result? or throwing any exception?

Comment: Yes, it is not returning any result or exception

Comment: Can you put breakpoint at `listBox1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];` and check you have any data? also see in db tables and confirm you have data?

Comment: Yes, when i hover on " ds.Tables[0] " then count shows 1 and there is data in db table as well. But it doesn't reflect in listbox

Comment: I just updated last binding piece, you can see the data now.

Comment: In wpf, these property(listbox1.DisplaMember & listbox1.valuemember) is not appearing. even listbox1.datasource

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly states the issue in your code. You should set `SelectCommand` before calling `Fill` which internally uses it.

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds, "ContactManager");
```

Comment: Hi, I used your code but when i click on button it doesn't perform any functionality without error message

Comment: You should show the xaml where you work with `listBox1`.

Comment: *<ListBox Height="253" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,47,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" />*

Comment: You should configure your `ListBox` accordingly. Set data template and bindings.